Force vim to use 4 spaces in reStructuredText
I am trying to write some rst files for documenting a Python package, but it is a nightmare to work on it.

When I press Enter I get 3 spaces:

This is text
   text after Enter


When I press Tab after Enter I get 3 + 1 spaces:

This is text
    text after ``Enter``, then ``Tab``

It is so hard to maintain a constant indentation. And it is so boring to have to press 3 spaces every time to maintain proper indentation.
Please note that I have an empty .vimrc.
In a foo.rst file, by typing :scriptnames, the last loaded .vim files are:
/usr/share/vim/vim91/ftplugin/rst.vim and /usr/share/vim/vim91/ftplugin/rst.vim.
The ftplugin/rst.vim file:
" reStructuredText filetype plugin file
" Language: reStructuredText documentation format
" Maintainer: Marshall Ward <marshall.ward@gmail.com>
" Original Maintainer: Nikolai Weibull <now@bitwi.se>
" Website: https://github.com/marshallward/vim-restructuredtext
" Latest Revision: 2020-03-31

if exists("b:did_ftplugin")
    finish
endif
let b:did_ftplugin = 1

let s:cpo_save = &cpo
set cpo&vim

"Disable folding
if !exists('g:rst_fold_enabled')
  let g:rst_fold_enabled = 0
endif

let b:undo_ftplugin = "setl com< cms< et< fo<"

setlocal comments=fb:.. commentstring=..\ %s expandtab
setlocal formatoptions+=tcroql

" reStructuredText standard recommends that tabs be expanded to 8 spaces
" The choice of 3-space indentation is to provide slightly better support for
" directives (..) and ordered lists (1.), although it can cause problems for
" many other cases.
"
" More sophisticated indentation rules should be revisited in the future.

if exists("g:rst_style") && g:rst_style != 0
    setlocal expandtab shiftwidth=3 softtabstop=3 tabstop=8
endif

if g:rst_fold_enabled != 0 && has('patch-7.3.867')  " Introduced the TextChanged event.
  setlocal foldmethod=expr
  setlocal foldexpr=RstFold#GetRstFold()
  setlocal foldtext=RstFold#GetRstFoldText()
  augroup RstFold
    autocmd TextChanged,InsertLeave <buffer> unlet! b:RstFoldCache
  augroup END
endif

let &cpo = s:cpo_save
unlet s:cpo_save

The indent/rst.vim file:
" Vim indent file
" Vim reST indent file
" Language: reStructuredText Documentation Format
" Maintainer: Marshall Ward <marshall.ward@gmail.com>
" Previous Maintainer: Nikolai Weibull <now@bitwi.se>
" Latest Revision: 2020-03-31
"                  2023 Aug 28 by Vim Project (undo_indent)

if exists("b:did_indent")
  finish
endif
let b:did_indent = 1

setlocal indentexpr=GetRSTIndent()
setlocal indentkeys=!^F,o,O
setlocal nosmartindent

let b:undo_indent = "setlocal indentexpr< indentkeys< smartindent<"

if exists("*GetRSTIndent")
  finish
endif

let s:itemization_pattern = '^\s*[-*+]\s'
let s:enumeration_pattern = '^\s*\%(\d\+\|#\)\.\s\+'
let s:note_pattern = '^\.\. '

function! s:get_paragraph_start()
    let paragraph_mark_start = getpos("'{")[1]
    return getline(paragraph_mark_start) =~ '\S' ? paragraph_mark_start : paragraph_mark_start + 1
endfunction

function GetRSTIndent()
  let lnum = prevnonblank(v:lnum - 1)
  if lnum == 0
    return 0
  endif

  let ind = indent(lnum)
  let line = getline(lnum)

  let psnum = s:get_paragraph_start()
  if psnum != 0
      if getline(psnum) =~ s:note_pattern
          let ind = 3
      endif
  endif

  if line =~ s:itemization_pattern
    let ind += 2
  elseif line =~ s:enumeration_pattern
    let ind += matchend(line, s:enumeration_pattern)
  endif

  let line = getline(v:lnum - 1)

  " Indent :FIELD: lines.  Don’t match if there is no text after the field or
  " if the text ends with a sent-ender.
   if line =~ '^:.\+:\s\{-1,\}\S.\+[^.!?:]$'
     return matchend(line, '^:.\{-1,}:\s\+')
   endif

  if line =~ '^\s*$'
    execute lnum
    call search('^\s*\%([-*+]\s\|\%(\d\+\|#\)\.\s\|\.\.\|$\)', 'bW')
    let line = getline('.')
    if line =~ s:itemization_pattern
      let ind -= 2
    elseif line =~ s:enumeration_pattern
      let ind -= matchend(line, s:enumeration_pattern)
    elseif line =~ '^\s*\.\.'
      let ind -= 3
    endif
  endif

  return ind
endfunction


Oops, thanks for pointing it out. The other post is deleted.

I can reproduce when g:rst_style is set. Can you check where this is :let? Easiest solution would be to set it to a false value or remove it altogether. Other than that, you could just specify your own indentation rules according to :help indent.txt.

you can try mine https://github.com/habamax/vim-rst

@Friedrich I commented everything in both {ftplugin,indent}/rst.vim} and set the values in the .vimrc. Now works. Still curious how it recognizes and highlights the syntax if I have commented everything related to .rst.

Recognize: :help :filetype, highlight: syntax/rst.vim. Also see :help ft-rst-plugin, just :let g:rst_style=0  should prevent the three-space thing. You should not edit your system config files, better to override them with user config.

@Friedrich Still the problem remains if I set :let g:rst_style=0 in the .vimrc. Moreover, even if I remove my .vimrc, restore the ftplugin and indent files, :echo g:rst_style returns 0.
